# Conditional expectation of throwing a die.

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

> Let $T$ denote the number of times we have to roll a fair dice before each face has appeared at least once and let $N$ denote the number of different faces appearing in the first six rolls. Then $E(T|N=3)$ is
>
> 1. $9$
> 2. $15$
> 3. $16$
> 4. $17$

First I didn't understand the problem fully. Conditional expectation is given by $$E(T=t|N=3)=\sum_{i} t_i\frac{P(T=t_i,N=3)}{P(N=3)}$$ Now how am I going to proceed from here. $N=3$ for first six throws so $P(N=3)=\frac{1}{2}$ right? Any hint or help would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: $P(N=3)$ is not $\frac12$

Comment: Ok then I must have mistaken. Can you give me a hint @MarkFischler

Comment: @KushalBhuyan Find the probability of throwing $6$ dice and having $3$ different numbers.

Comment: $P(N=3)=\frac{{6}\cdot{5}\cdot{4}\cdot{4}\cdot{4}\cdot{4}}{{6}\cdot{6}\cdot{6}\cdot{6}\cdot{6}\cdot{6}}$, is that correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend using the formula, since then you need to calculate $P(T,N=3)$ which isn't a lot easier than the conditional.

Start by imagining N=3. This means that after the sixth roll, there have been three different faces seen. So the expected time to see all 6 conditional on this is $$ 6 + \mbox{(expected time it takes to see the last three faces)}.$$

So we need calculate the additioal time it takes to roll the last 3 faces. When you start attempting this, any one of the 3 faces you haven't seen yet will be a new face. Thus on each attempt, you have a 3/6 = 1/2 probability of getting a new face. The expected number of independent trials to see an event with probability $p$ is $1/p$.  Thus, the expected time to roll the fourth new face starting from when you rolled the third is 1/(1/2) = 2. After you roll the fourth face, the probability of rolling a new face goes down to 2/6 = 1/3. So the expected time to roll the 5th face is 3. Finally, after the fifth is roll you only have a 1/6 chance of rolling that final face, so the expected time to do that is 6.

So the expected time to see the last three faces is 2 + 3  + 6 = 11. So the answer is 6 +11 = 17

Comment: "last three faces is 2 + 3/2 + 6 = 9.5" Shouldn't that be $2+3+6 = 11$? The answer would finally be $17$, which fits OP's options.

Comment: @O.VonSeckendorff Whoops, thank you!

Comment: I didn't understand this line --"Starting from roll 7 with 3 faces seen, you have a probability of 1/2 of rolling a new face on each attempt". Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @KushalBhuyan . Edited to elaborate that part. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: Yes it does now. Thank you very much. +1